# Timeline for Mashiach and Gog U'Magog

Tags: messiah

The Gemara in [Avodah Zarah 3b](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.3b.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says that in the days of Mashiach many non-Jews are going to want to convert to join the Jewish people but then when they see the war of Gog U'Magog they will regret joining and want to go back to their old ways. This clearly implies that Gog U'Magog will occur after the coming of Mashiach. Any sources for opinions on the timeline of these events?

Comment: What's missing from the gemara?

Comment: details........

Comment: Have you been listening Rabbi Isser Zalman Weisberg? For the last month he’s been speaking about this subject in detail.

Comment: If you’re interested, start here: https://youtu.be/QCQ1ayyRvGU